# X and Y does not match in canvas with offsets

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have tried to draw an image in my canvas then try to click inside the image with the mouse. But the X and Y positions are not correct, i took offset's into consideration and corrected for that but they are still incorrect.

I currently don't know how else to solve it. I have made a fiddle to replicate the situation including the parent div the canvas resides inside of.

***http://jsfiddle.net/bX5Dr/8/***

The code i used to take offset into consideration, which appears not to be working:

```
function getxy(event,el){
    canvasX = event.pageX - el.offsetLeft,
    canvasY = event.pageY - el.offsetTop;
    return {x:canvasX, y:canvasY}
 //does not give the same answer as you would expect when using drawImage();
}
```

In the fiddle the top left corner of the canvas should be `0,0` but it is not according to my calculation i used.

Comment: tried removing the margin and border pixels in the calculation?

Comment: I have not - i thought offset took that into consideration =/ how would i incorporate them ?

Comment: Your element offsetLeft is always 0 since you're applying the margin-left to it's parent... change it to:
`canvasX = event.pageX - el.parentNode.offsetLeft,` http://jsfiddle.net/bX5Dr/9/

Comment: Ah i see, what if there is a bunch of divs higher up in the hierarchy. For example in my site theres a few grandparent great grandparent divs etc would i have to take them all into account too ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using element.getBoundingClientRect(), as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11396681/594406)?

```
function getxy(event,el){
    var rect =  el.getBoundingClientRect();
    canvasX = event.pageX -  rect.left,
    canvasY = event.pageY - rect.top;
    return {x:canvasX, y:canvasY}
}
```

Comment: It works but i get floating point numbers in return. Is that normal ?

Comment: I'm inclined to give this the correct answer result solely to help others in future, as this is much more elegant solution.

Comment: indeed, [element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect) returns a [TextRectangle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIDOMClientRect), which have float properties

Comment: Note, i just noticed it gives a different answer for me if i have dev tools open =/ is there a solution for that? If i scroll down and the hover over canvas the scroll is added to it =/ how strange.

Answer (score 1):

Your element offsetLeft is always 0 since you're applying the style to it's parent...

change the offset target to:

`canvasX = event.pageX - el.offsetParent.offsetLeft,`

http://jsfiddle.net/bX5Dr/9

For more info on calculating an object offset relative to the page, considering it's parent nodes, see: 
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html

Answer (score 0):

What I meant was you can compensate for the `margin-left:20px` and `border:1px`like this;

```
canvasX = event.pageX - el.offsetLeft-21,
canvasY = event.pageY - el.offsetTop-1;
```

but yea , why play with the child element when others have given the solution to change the parent's offset